# Is there no word for objects/'things' in Hebrew aside from referring to things as 'words'?

Tags: hebrew, mysticism-kabbalah, language

I read the following passage and wonder about the first couple of sentences, which are pretty practical and I wonder if they're 'empirically' true. In common Hebrew language, how are 'things' referred to? For example, if one says "what is that thing over there?" then does the equivalent Hebrew sentence translate literally as "what is that word over there?"

Looking up דברים it translates as "stuff" which is like "things", but is there another/deeper meaning to the word Devarim דברים ? I understand Hebrew, especially interpreted by Kabbalists, can be esoteric and have lots of hermeneutic rabbit holes. In this case I'm wondering how present the phenomenon is in everyday language around referring to objects and things.

> "There is no word in Hebrew for ‘thing.’ Objects are called
>   Devarim/words. An object is a specific vibration, every thing, or
>   subject, is an expression of a variant frequency. ‘Things’ are mere
>   externalized manifestations of internal, cosmic vibrations. Creation
>   begins with a subtle, (spiritual) vibration and movement within the
>   Infinite Creator, which then gives rise to a physical vibration of
>   energy, which is eventually solidified into matter. At every moment,
>   every physical time/space expression is an externalized manifestation
>   of a spiritual vibration. Man below is a reflection of the Above. The
>   power of human speech below mimics the creative power of Divine
>   speech. Divine speech creates reality and human speech qualifies
>   reality, calling it good or bad. On a deeper level, our words and how
>   we language our thoughts is a process of continually creating the
>   world around us. In other words, things are to us what we say they
>   are... Just as we have the power to create with speech, we have the
>   equivalent ability to destroy through speech. Our words, which are our
>   projections and vibrations, alter the inner frequency of the universe,
>   for good and for the opposite."
>
> Rav DovBer Pinson

Comment: The top paragraph asks for literal meaning and the second paragraph asks for deeper mystical meaning. I believe the latter is not a strictly Hebrew language question and therefore defensible as in-scope, but it also seems to be answered in the affirmative by the quotation. Are you looking for corroboration of the quotation?

Comment: http://www.morfix.co.il/en/חפץ

Comment: As your title is clearly disproved - דבר is not "a word" in Hebrew, please consider to rephrase your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. The word דבר is used in everyday Hebrew just as freely as "thing" is used in English.
2. You're seemingly wrong, the word "דבר" alone is never translated as "a word". And the root דבר as speech is used only as a verb, not a noun. Also, I don't recall where in Tanach דבר is used as a single word.
3. There are synonyms to דבר, e.g. חפץ (stuff) or עצם (object).
4. Technically you might be right, as the physical reality might be represented through scientific "language" of formulas - math, physics, chemistry etc. So every object is seen as a representation of scientific "words".
5. Speculations are good, but maybe it's the other way around - the speech is called לדבר because of its objectification (לדבר דברים), as every word represents a "thing" therefore the speech is "things"?